An Application of Closed Graph Theorem or Open Mapping Theorem?
I have encontered an exercise which I have no clue:

Suppose $(E, \Vert \cdot \Vert_E)$ and $(F, \Vert \cdot \Vert_F)$ are two Banach spaces, the image set of $u \in \mathcal{L}(E, F)$,
$$
\mathcal{R}(u):=\{y\in F: u(x)=y, x\in F\},
$$
is a closed set, and $\dim \ker(u) < \infty$. Let $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ be another norm on $E$, and there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\forall x \in E, \Vert x \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert_E$. Prove there exists $M>0$ satisfying
$$
\Vert x \Vert_E \leq M(\Vert u(x) \Vert_F + \Vert x \Vert), \forall x \in E.
$$
Hint: Prove by contradiction.

And here's what I have tried.
Since $\forall x \in E, \Vert x \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert_E$, the map $id_E:(E, \Vert \cdot \Vert_E) \to (E, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is continuous. Then, the open mapping theorem implies that $id_E$ is an open mapping, so there exists a constant $M_1>0$ such that $\forall x \in E, \Vert x \Vert_E \leq M_1\Vert x \Vert$. Thus, the problem is simplied to finding a constant $M_2>0$ satisfying
$$
\Vert x \Vert_E \leq M_2\Vert u(x) \Vert_F, \forall x \in E.
$$
Namely, we need to prove that the inverse of $u$ is a continuous map. Take the quotient space $E/\ker(u)$ so that $u$ is injective and $u^{-1}$ exisits. Yet, I have failed to apply the closed graph theorem or the open mapping theorem to show that $u^{-1}$ is continuous. I doubt that $u^{-1}$ might not be continuous and the simplification I've done above might be misleading. Also, I fail to see how to "prove by contradiction".
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
(P.S. This is the first time I post on Math Stackexchange. Please let me know if there's anything I can improve.)

This was answered before please see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2772964/1315948

@Steen82 Thank you very much.
